# White spaces in HTML attributes

Tags: php, html

Some of my `class` attributes are generated by PHP, so sometimes there are extra whitespaces in HTML output, in example:

```
class=" hey  joe "
```

As we can see there are:
- empty first char
- two empty chars between `hey` and `joe`
- empty last char

May it cause some problems for browsers, web crawlers or other problems?

Comment: Please include **THE** code that print the above HTML. Otherwise, this is a webmaster question

Comment: If it bugs you use `trim()` before outputting class names, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no problem with this. The class attribute accepts any number of classes separated by whitespaces. Trailing and leading whitespaces are not significant here.

Please see [White Space handling in attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.7) and [Attribute-Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize) for authoritative details.